# How to save an image in Google Apps Script

Tags: http, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

My goal is to post an image via an Android app to this Google Apps Script and append some data to a Google Sheet.

All of the plumbing is functioning. I can call `doPost` from the Android app and pass text data. But the data for the image is being sent to the script, when it saves the file, it cannot be opened in Google Drive. The file in Google Drive is shown, with the correct image type, but it cannot be opened in Drive or on my PC after downloading.

```
function doPost(e) {
  var action = e.parameter.action;
  //  if(action == "postFood"){
    try {

      var contentType = "image/jpeg";
      var contents = e.postData.contents; // I have tried to use Utilities.base64decode, but  it doesn't work
      var fileName = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT', 'yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a');
      
      var imageBlob = Utilities.newBlob(contents, contentType, fileName);

      return handleImageAndAppendRow(e.parameter, imageBlob);
    } catch (error) {
      return ContentService.createTextOutput("{message:'Error', details:'" + error + "'}").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    }
  // }
}
```

I have a test method that downloads an image (opposed to being posted), and it calls `handleImageAndAppendRow()` successfully.

Working test method:

```
function downloadTestPic(){
  var contentType = "image/jpeg";
  var options = {
      "method" : "get",
      "contentType": contentType,
      'muteHttpExceptions': true
  };

  var url = "https://www.wksusa.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/IMG-0423-scaled-e1658446014847-610x350.jpeg";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  
  var blob = response.getBlob();
  blob.setContentTypeFromExtension();
  
var sampleData = {
    'date': '1/4/2024',
    'meal': 'Lunch',
    'description': 'Chipotle'
  }
  
handleImageAndAppendRow(sampleData, blob)
}
```

I have confirmed that the Android app code can post images to other services just fine. There's just something funky about how the image data is being handled in the Apps Script.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Here's the Android code:

```
private fun run(foodDescription: String, selectedDate: String, selectedMeal: String, imageFile: File) {
        println("Saving $imageFile.name")

        val requestBody = MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("action", "postFood")
            .addFormDataPart("date", selectedDate)
            .addFormDataPart("meal", selectedMeal)
            .addFormDataPart("description", foodDescription)
            .addFormDataPart("image", imageFile.name, imageFile.asRequestBody(MEDIA_TYPE_JPEG))
            .build()


//        val request = Request.Builder() // This works!!
//            .header("Authorization", "Client-ID 9199fdef135c122")
//            .url("https://api.imgur.com/3/image")
//            .post(requestBody)
//            .build()
        
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url("https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwQ1nLEzgMwHsa3iSovL5zNpZG9jE-T4_Bsg_yQs0E7pc6tpscvKc-4oakOCZMyB4vk/exec")
            .post(imageFile.asRequestBody(MEDIA_TYPE_JPEG))
//            .post(requestBody)
            .build()

        client.newCall(request).execute().use { response ->
            if (!response.isSuccessful) throw IOException("Unexpected code $response")
            Log.d("API lame", response.body!!.string());
            println(response.body!!.string())
        }
    }
```

Here's an example of an image I am uploading: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ww1SgEAqHJh-RSjraNAB28_jjCEVYOxp/view?usp=drive_link

And here's an example of how it is saved: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IKhinCWfcgOrL5YUfl-Hmna5257hETEz/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Can you provide the sample value of `e.postData.contents` in your situation?

Comment: I haven't figured out how to properly debug the doPost function when called externally so it's a little tough. But I edited my question to include links to the images with issues. Thank you for looking, @Tanaike !

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot see your added files. But, about `I haven't figured out how to properly debug the doPost function when called externally so it's a little tough`, in this case, please add `DriveApp.createFile("sample.txt", JSON.stringify(e))` just after the line of `function doPost(e) {`. And redeploy Web Apps and test it again. By this, the value of `e` is exported as a text file in the root folder. By this, I can confirm the value of the event object `e`. By this, I guess that I might be able to propose a modification point.